# MySQL error 1064 in CREATE TABLE statements in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

```
createTable('members', 'user VARCHAR(16), pass VARCHAR(16),
            INDEX(user(6))');

createTable('messages', 
           'id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            auth VARCHAR(16), recip VARCHAR(16), pm CHAR(1),
            time INT UNSIGNED, message VARCHAR(4096),
            INDEX(auth(6)), INDEX(recip(6))');

createTable('friends', 'user VARCHAR(16), friend VARCHAR(16),
            INDEX(user(6)), INDEX(friend(6))');

createTable('profiles', 'user VARCHAR(16), text VARCHAR(4096),
            INDEX(user(6))');
```

***Can someone please help me figure out what's wrong?***

Comment: that does not look like sql syntax...

Comment: 1064: "You have an error in your MySQL syntax." or whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql syntax is not correct. try this instead.

```
CREATE Table `members`
(
    `user` VARCHAR(16), 
    `pass` VARCHAR(16),
    INDEX (`user`)
);

Create Table `messages`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `auth` VARCHAR(16), 
    `recip` VARCHAR(16), 
    `pm` CHAR(1),
    `time` INT UNSIGNED, 
    `message` VARCHAR(4096),
    INDEX(`auth`, `recip`)
);


CREATE Table `friends`
(
    `user` VARCHAR(16), 
    `friend` VARCHAR(16),
    INDEX(`user`, `friend`)
);

create Table `profiles` 
(
    `user` VARCHAR(16), 
    `text` VARCHAR(4096),
    INDEX(`user`)
);
```